# Find a Control by propertyname

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my content page structure:

1. Listview with 3 columns - label(s.no), Imagebutton(view Record), label(item name).
   The Imagebutton has oncommand="view".When clicked, it displays, that row's details in the respective textboxes that are below.
2. Textbox(itemname)
3. Textbox(itemcode)

Problem:

When the cursor is in any of the textbox, and I press 'Enter', it is firing the 'View' command event, meaning... I get the details of the first row in the listview, displayed in these textboxes.
I do not want this to happen. Is this behaviour due to the 'DefaultButton' property set somewhere? I tried finding the same in the entire solution but could not.

There are master and content pages and this issue is in every content page.

How can I find out, which control has this property, or what causes this behaviour.

Comment: The question's title is so miss-leading. Please edit that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of a HTML page.

In ASP.NET, the `Panel` control has a `DefaultButton` property that you can set and will change this behaviour. You can put textboxes in a Panel and set the DefaultButton property of the panel.